# Principal component analysis with a limited sample size

Tags: pca, factor-analysis, confirmatory-factor

Thanks in advance!

I am attempting to quantify hospital resources using database derived variables that are all believed based on theory to be important for surgical patients.

There are about **70 variables and 140 hospitals**, so dimensional reduction is key.

I also have data on tens of thousands of patients at these hospitals. And my end goal would he to examine the effects of hospital resources (as quantified in a meaningful way) on several outcomes, I.e. 30d mortality.

Although ideally, I think an exploratory followed by confirmatory factor analysis would be best, then using factor scores in multivariate analyses, my limited number of hospitals makes it impossible to split into a train and test set. This is population level data so getting a bigger sample is (within a reasonable time frame) not possible.

Would it be reasonable to use principal component analysis to create component scores, and then use derived scores in a multivariate analysis examining my outcome of interest?

I understand that PCA is not perfect for this front, but I am trying to do the most sound analysis I can with the data available.

All the best.